# Where we can find stderr/stdi/stdout in ASP.NET-MVC/IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have native C++ dll which I am calling from ASP.NET MVC(IIS web server) using PInvoke.The thing is that whenever a C++ function uses stderr/stdi/stdout I am not seeing them in IIS logs(W3SVC*). In a .NET console application, I can see them in the console but where can I see them in an IIS app?

Comment: IIS worker processes are not console applications, so there is no such things and the output from C++ side is nowhere to find. However, if that C++ dll uses standard debugging output functions, then DebugView can collect and show them to you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview

Comment: @LexLi thanks I tried but unfortunately not getting anything

Comment: BTW, have you tried IIS Express? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line It does have a console and maybe you can see the output from there.

Comment: Yes IIS Express helped here Thanks a lot Lex Li